# Help! I poured the syrup over my Baklava before I baked it. Is it ruined?

Tags: baking, syrup

I accidentally poured the syrup over my Baklava before I baked it.  Did I ruin it?  Is there anything I can do to salvage it?

Comment: Hopefully you just went ahead and put it in the oven by now.  It'll be a bit sticky and mushy, but should still be edible.

Comment: You can try straining the syrup as much as you can and bake like that.

Comment: Can you edit your question and finish it please? It looks like you submitted it halfway through a sentence

Comment: Cooked sugary goodness always tastes nice - as long as the sugar doesn't burn.  When in doubt, disguise with icecream :)

Comment: can you add another layer of dough?

Answer (score 22):

You have ruined it as baklava, pouring the syrup on before baking means it won't crisp up, you can't pour the syrup out and get the same result. However, you may as well just bake it and see what comes out, it won't be baklava but it may taste good. Feel free to post an answer if you do and tell us what it was like.

Comment: While I agree fully, a lot of baklava is sodden with syrup and oversweet anyway, so with any luck you'll still make something as good as you'd buy in a shop.

Comment: Unlikely @MarkWildon, decent baklava is still crispy, even if it is covered in syrup. This makes me want baklava now!

Comment: Everyone that has access to good baklava, take a moment to be grateful lol. A lot of people only ever get lumps of soggy phyllo and pecans held together with honey flavored corn syrup and the tenuous dream of something better.

Comment: @kitukwfyer +1, I think that's the most poetic thing I've read all day.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest baking at 50ºF lower if you have not commenced baking, for a longer time. Just check visually.

Comment: I can't see this helping. Could you add a rationale?

Comment: It would help by making sure it cooks through without burning or drying the outside.